# vsftp on RedHat (CentOS) – Is there a way to disable uploading files by mime/type or extension?

Tags: centos, ftp, vsftpd

E.g., disable `*.file` and `*.html` uploads? 
Or enable only `*.avi` and `*.mov`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [deny_file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/vsftpd.conf.5.html#contenttoc5) directive, with something like this:

```
deny_file={*.file,*.html}
```